# Stripping href links with HtmlAgilityPack from webpage

Tags: c#, nodes, href, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HtmlAgilityPack to grab links from a website.

```
//part of html from source
string htmlSource="<a class=" ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24" href="http://hoogbegaafdleren.blogspot.com/2011/05/topstudenten-detecteren-in-de.html" target="_blank" data-4fb="5995cb507b349">hoogbegaafdlerenblog: Wat <b>heb</b> je <b>vandaag</b> op school <b>geleerd</b>?</a><a class=" ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24" href="http://gietjes.blogspot.com/2014/09/wat-heb-ik-vandaag-geleerd.html" target="_blank" data-4fb="5995cb507b667">Gietjes Corner: Wat <b>heb</b> <b>ik</b> <b>vandaag</b> <b>geleerd</b>?!</a>"
```

this is the part that analyse the html and should put the links in a list

```
public static List<String> GetLinksFromWebsite(string htmlSource)
{
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlSource);
    return doc.DocumentNode
            .SelectNodes("......")
            .Select(node => node.Attributes["......"].Value)
            .ToList();
}
```

What should I fill .SelectNodes and .Select with to get the URL which is in the href tag?

**EDIT:**

I did try selecting the nodes with

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
```

but unfortunately this only return the nodes in the html which looked like

```
"<a href="http://..................."
```

but for my code I only need the links in the

```
<a class=" ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24" href="http://.........."
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT 2**

to be complete: I'm trying to analyze search results. So this would be the code:

```
    public void Start()
    {
            System.IO.StreamWriter body = new StreamWriter(@"body.txt",     append: true);
            string LookUp="https://search.yahoo.com/search;?p=%27who+is+john+doe%27"
            var htmlSource = client.DownloadString(LookUp);

            foreach (var item in GetLinksFromWebsite(htmlSource))
            {
                 body.WriteLine(item);    
            }

    }


        public static List<String> GetLinksFromWebsite(string htmlSource)
        {
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(htmlSource);
            return doc.DocumentNode
                    .SelectNodes("......")
                    .Select(node => node.Attributes["......"].Value)
                    .ToList();
        }
```

where the "p=" tag is the actual string to search for.

This will return a html with a lot of wanted and unwanted links. The unwanted hrefs are the yahoo onces which I do not need. The wanted hrefs, which are the search results all are tagged like:

```
<a class=" ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24" href="https://
```

and I'm only interested in these hrefs. Unfortunately if I make my select like :

```
    .SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    .Select(node => node.Attributes["href"].Value)
```

I'm only getting the unwanted yahoo refs

Comment: @Nkosi, I don't believe my question is similar to the question pointed at. I tried this approach before, but this didn't work. Please see my edit

Comment: I think you need to put a little more work into your question.  I can't tell if you are receiving too many links and want to narrow it down to that specific link or if your link isn't getting returned at all.  What does the second statement in your edit mean if the former "'only' returns the nodes int he html which looked like ..." since for the query it should be returning the one you want as well.  What is the difference in the links you want (and don't get?) and the ones you do get but don't want?

Comment: @Jason, please have a look at my second EDIT